# How to give Facebook permission for accessing user data in facebook-sdk-3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an application in which I'm using `Facebook` login for authentication and stuff. `facebook sdk 3.0` needs some permission for accessing user data such as profile picture, emailID,publish_stram and etc. How to give permission in the code for accessing those things. Till now I'm able to get `fb_access_token`. Here is my code:

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    // make request to the /me API
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                // callback after Graph API response with
                                // user
                                // object
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        fb_user_id = user.getId();
                                    }

                                    Session session = Session
                                            .getActiveSession();
                                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                                        access_token = session
                                                .getAccessToken();
                                    }

                                    new postFBData().execute();
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
```

Taken this code snippet from Facebook samples. How to give permission before accessing `access_token` from FB?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling Session.openActiveSession will only give you basic permissions (until you've requested additional ones). You also need to separate the read and publish permission requests.

In your case, I would do something like:

```
Session session = // create a new Session using Session.Builder
Session.OpenRequest openRequest = // create an OpenRequest using Session.OpenRequest
openRequest.setPermissions( READ_PERMISSION_LIST );
session.openForRead(openRequest);
Session.setActiveSession(session);
```

Then, once you've opened the session,

```
// check if you already have publish permissions first
if (!Session.getActiveSession.getPermissions.contains("publish_stream")) {
  Session.NewPermissionsRequest permissionRequest = // create a NewPermissionsRequest
  permissionRequest.setPermissions( PUBLISH_PERMISSION_LIST);
  Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(permissionRequest);
}
```

Comment: I have to get these many permissions `user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,read_stream,user_checkins,friends_checkins,friends_likes,email,user_likes`. Can you tell where to put the above code and when to call those permission methods?

Comment: these are all read permissions with the exception of "publish_stream". Generally, anything that's only data access is a read permission, and anything that can modify user data (including manage permissions, and some events related ones) is a publish permission.

Comment: is post still fb.request() ?

Comment: All methods in the Facebook class have been deprecated, and are there only for backwards compatibility. There's a new Request class for making graph requests, and an upgrade guide for upgrading from 2.0 to 3.0 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/

Comment: @MingLi Can you help me with this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login

I'm not getting any answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is how you authorize a certain kind of functionality in the String[]

```
 fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[] {"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener(){

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on Facebook error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values)
            {
                updateButtonImage();

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this using the facebook SDK v3 for this is for v2?

Comment: its when you login you specify the permission you are going to need in the String[], if you reference the site you can see all the String permissions you can actually use

Comment: Please do not use Facebook.authorize if you're starting a new project with v3, that method has been deprecated, and only works for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I understand that it works, it's meant to because v3 is backwards compatible with v2. But it's deprecated, meaning that it will not be supported into the future, and anyone starting a new project should NOT use it.

Comment: ok, thank you, i didnt know that, ill make the change myself, itll probably save me some trouble in the future